# Portfolio Analytics Optimization

Tags: r, portfolio-optimization

I have a large dataset, 10,000 investments I am trying to create an optimized portfolio for.  The portfolio has 3 restrictions. Long Only, Only 50 assets can be selected and every invested asset has the same weight.  I would like to find the max sharpe portfolio and the minSD portfolio for a given return.

```
> funds = colnames(dfxts)
> returns = dfxts
> df.con = portfolio.spec(assets = funds)
> df.con = add.constraint(portfolio = df.con, type = "long_only")
> df.con = add.constraint(portfolio = df.con, type = "box", min = (1/n - .01/n), max = (1/n + .01/n))
> 
> df.con = add.constraint(portfolio = df.con, type = "position_limit", max_pos = n)
> 
> df.con = add.constraint(portfolio = df.con, type = "return", return_targe = r)
> 
> df.con = add.constraint(portfolio = df.con, type = "weight_sum_constraint", min_sum = .99, max_sum = 1.01)
> minSDdf <- add.objective(portfolio=df.con, 
+                                  type="risk", 
+                                  name="StdDev")

opt = optimize.portfolio(R = returns, portfolio = df.con, optimize_method = "DEoptim", trace = TRUE)
```

This is taking over 10 hours to optimize.  How can I change the constraints or optimizer to make this faster?  I would like it to be under 10 minutes if possible.  Thanks,

Not sure if this is working correctly.  I edited the objective function in the vignette,

```
   > OF2 <- function(x, Data) {
    +  w <- 1/sum(x)
    +  -(sum(r*w))/(sum(w * w * Data$Sigma[x, x]))
    +  }
```

The objective function should return a negative value, but it keeps giving me a positive value?  Why is this happending

Comment: the method of constraining weights to be within an epsilon of (1/n) does not seem a very efficient way to do it.

Comment: your problem is discrete optimization rather than continuous

Comment: Do you have any resource I can look into for discrete optimizations?

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22208/portfolio-optimization-with-equal-weight-for-assets-selected  Here is a sample of the dataset I am trying to optimize

Comment: It seems your question is about computational efficiency. However, choosing a portfolio with ~10K free variables is unlikely to yield good future performance. Perhaps you can solve both problems by applying some domain knowledge about the 10K assets to reduce the problem size.

Answer (score 2):

A problem very similar to yours is described -- including R code -- in a vignette of the NMOF package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/vignettes/LSselect.pdf 
For the Sharpe ratio, you simply need to write a new objective function.